# (Device) AJAX Request using Json for Netflix Issue

Tags: android, jquery, ajax, json, device

I am creating a simple application for the Mobile to retrieve netflix information via AJAX request with json. This works perfectly well on the browser.

I am having a problem triggering the success of the ajax request. I have been reading and searching every where but no solution has fixed my issue on the device (emulator, ultimately the android). I am using Phonegap.

Here is are my CDNs:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.templates/beta1/jquery.tmpl.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a4/jquery.mobile-1.0a4.min.js"></script>
```

and here is my code:

```
var myMoviePeopleURL = "http://odata.netflix.com/Catalog/People?$top=200&$format=json&$callback=?";

        $.ajax({
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            url: myMoviePeopleURL,
            success: function () {alert('Success');},
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(textStatus);
                alert(errorThrown);
            },
        });
```

I receive a parse error and function not called. The device is fired up before the document so it is not a internet issue. I have checked this. It seems to either be a syntax issue or a compatibility issue (with the device).

Reminder: I need this to work on the device. Browser works just fine with this code.

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Remove the extra comma after `alert(errorThrown);},` <---

Comment: have you tried with `crossDomain:true` ? could not find any errors with the code.

Comment: thank you for your help! I have tried both of those solutions but neither one of them has solve my issue. I tried another web service, blockbusters, and it works successfully. I believe the problem may actually be the authentication even though you may not need it for browsers I believe you may need it for netflix on the android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have spoken with another application developer at my workplace and he claimed to have found a bug in the Netflix API. He has emailed them. Like I had said earlier, this phonegap application worked fine on the phone with Blockbusters BBYOpen.

Thanks again for your help guys!